# WPF Window set Focus

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, window, setfocus

I have a WPF Window which I only create one time and then Show() and Hide() several times. Now I am searching a way to set the focus on a element on each Show(). Where and how can I do this?

Comment: use Activated event of your window

Comment: just to be picky: this is not a user interface guideline but from user experience users do not like messing with what they have set. Ie. if I set focus to a textbox then alt-tab out to copy some value if you hide and show the form I expect to be still in that textbox. But of course your question can be inspired by a user requirement. in that case just forget everything :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In WPF there are two main concepts that pertain to focus: keyboard focus and logical focus. Keyboard focus refers to the element that receives keyboard input and logical focus refers to the element in a focus scope that has focus. These concepts are discussed in detail in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx) overview.

You can probably write you own ShowHide method by including both Window.Show/Hide and element.Focus functionalities in order to handle both in the same method.

Answer (score 33):

Just call Element.Focus() on the element you want to focus.

If you mean bring focus to the window try calling window.Activate()