# Wpf window Showdialog not getting focus

Tags: c#, wpf

I am calling a method using delegate to show a color window but that window not getting focus,It is working fine with mouse but for touch it requires one extra click to get focus.

```
 ColorPickerWindow colorPicker = new ColorPickerWindow ();
        colorPicker.Owner = this;
        colorPicker.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        colorPicker.SetColor(MenuColor);
        colorPicker.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Give a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395645/wpf-window-set-focus

Answer (score 1):

Just call `Element.Focus()` on the element you want to focus.

If you mean bring focus to the window try calling `window.Activate()`

Source : [WPF Window set Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395645/wpf-window-set-focus)

Comment: How would you call window.Activate or Element.Focus(), while the UI thread is blocked on .ShowDialog() ?

Answer (score 1):

I found that `window.ShowDialog()` fails to get window focus (pops under) when `.ShowDialog()` is called on a thread other than the UI thread for your main window.

For me the problem went away when I made sure to `.Invoke()` my `.ShowDialog()` on the correct UI thread.

Comment: This is a great point. I'm also having this issue at the moment and it seems like even after Invoking the call on the main UI thread. Have you managed to get this to work for you?