# Selfmade OnScreenKeyboard needs second tap to react

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a TextBox UserControl which shows a OnScreenKeyboard by clicking it. The CodeBehind of my TextBox which starts the OnScreenKeyboard looks like this:

```
private void TextBoxText_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox textbox = sender as TextBox;
            US_Keyboard keyboardWindow = new US_Keyboard(textbox, Window.GetWindow(this));
            if (keyboardWindow.ShowDialog() == true)
                textbox.Text = keyboardWindow.InputSource.Text;
        }
```

The OnScreenKeyboard is a partial class which inherits from Window. The Constructor of the OnScreenKeyboard looks like this:

```
    public US_Keyboard(TextBox owner, Window wndOwner)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Owner = wndOwner;
        this.DataContext = this;

        //Delete text in textbox
        if (InputSource.Text.Length > 0)
        {
            OldTextBoxValue = InputSource.Text;
            InputSource.Text = "";
        }

        //Set caret to start point of textbox
        AdornerLayer layer = AdornerLayer.GetAdornerLayer(owner);
        CaretAdorner adorner = new CaretAdorner(owner);
        adorner.OffsetX = _CaretOffsetXDefault;
        layer.Add(adorner);
        _adorner = adorner;
        _layer = layer;

        SetKeyboardSize();
        SetKeyboardPosition();
    }
```

So far everything works fine, except one thing: After the OnScreenKeyboard-Window shows up, it needs a second tap to react. It looks like it has no focus and needs one click to get the focus. How can i fix this?

I already tried the following in the constructor, but it does not help:

```
this.Focus();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF Window set Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6395645/wpf-window-set-focus)

Comment: It sounds like the same question, but the solution doesn't work for me

Comment: I would be more concerned about needing focus... shouldn't an on-screen-keyboard ideally work by receiving mouse clicks while the primary input focus stays in a different application that receives the input?

Comment: i see your concerns and i agree with you. nevertheless i need a quick solution for my application

Comment: could you attempt to subscribe to IsVisibleChanged, and then call Focus() once the event is fired?

Comment: i testet it, nothing changed @Milan

Comment: One more desperate attempt. What about yourTextbox.isloaded event calling keyboard.focus for itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using Win32 API:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace YourSolution
{
    static class WindowExtensions
    {
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        internal static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

        public static void SetFocus(this Window window)
        {
            var handle = new WindowInteropHelper(window).Handle;
            SetForegroundWindow(handle);
        }
    }
}
```

When you want to focus a window, use `window.SetFocus();`.
Note: The window you want to focus must be loaded before you call `SetFocus`.

Comment: why should i consider using win32 api?

Comment: @jimmmmyjooo Because you said the `Focus` method didn't work. This API is not very complex, why not have a try?

Comment: using win32 api doesn't help

Comment: Then there may be something preventing your keyboard from getting the focus. Comment other codes until `this.Focus()` works as normal to find out what's wrong. Hope this can help you.